# Why is not picking up the message id? how to solve

Tags: javascript, while-loop, alert

I have this code that scans my page looking for divs with a tag "message" but I would like it to give an alert with the number in this tag. Why is it not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateElement() {
var allDivs=document.getElementsByTagName('div'), i=0,d;
while(d=allDivs[i++]){
    if(d.getAttributeNode('message')){
    var ID = $(this).attr("message");
    alert(ID);
    }
}
}
onload=function(){updateElement()}
</script>

<div message="1">2</div>
<div message="2">3</div>
<div message="3">3</div>
```

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) to see the error messages. `$(this).attr()` is jQuery but you haven't included jQuery.

Comment: @dholakiyaankit Are you sure you aren't missing anything on that suggestion?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>Sorry ! abhitalks :D

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not what you think it is. Try this:

```
var ID = $(d).attr("message");
```

Also, you need to make sure you have included a `script` reference to JQuery if you want to use it.

[Here is a working example with JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/49wyj/)

---

If you don't want to use JQuery you can do it without...

```
while (d = allDivs[i++]) {
    var message = d.getAttributeNode('message');
    if (message ) {
        var ID = message.value;
        alert(ID);
    }
}
```

[Here is a working example that doesn't use JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Be7Qy/)